# Run javascript code on page load (twitter-bootstrap popup)

Tags: javascript, .net, twitter-bootstrap, popup

I wrote some code using twitter-Bootstrap and .net to show a popup when you press the button. Here is my code piece:

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>           
            <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">                
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>... some info...</p>
                </div>                
            </div>
```

when I press the button, the popup appears. But I want to make appear the popup on page load independent from the button. How can I make this maybe using javascript or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can just trigger it on page load.

```
$(function() {
   $("#myModal").modal("show");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use window.onload.

```
window.onload=function(){
    $("#myModal").modal("show");
}
```